# awk to match two files and output the difference with column name & value

Tags: awk, gawk

I want to compare two files with awk and output the unmatched  columns.

what i have tried till now

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==NR{
        for(i=0;i<=NF; i++){
        a[i];

        }next;
        }
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if($i in a){
        {printf("Match: %s , col-> %d" $i,i-1)}
        else

        {printf("UN- Match: %s , col-> %d" $i,i-1)
        }

        }
        }'
```

but this one is of no use.

Here is what i need.

```
Example:
file 1
1,2,3,4,5,6


file 2
1,2,5,4,5,7

Output

col 3 -> 3,5
col 6 -> 6,7
```

Comment: You can also use diff for this. diff -y file1 file2 > output

Comment: Is your real input pipe-delimited? Does each file contain more than one line? Please [edit] your question to clarify

Comment: updated. and yes my original file is pipe delimited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk, will work for more rows as well

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[NR,i]=$i;next}
{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(a[FNR,i]!=$i)print "Row:"FNR,"Col:"i"->",a[FNR,i]","$i}' file{1,2}
```

---

#### Example

*Input*

File1

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
6,5,4,3,2,1
```

File2

```
1,2,5,4,5,7
6,4,4,3,1,1
```

*Output*

```
Row:1 Col:3-> 3,5
Row:1 Col:6-> 6,7
Row:2 Col:2-> 5,4
Row:2 Col:5-> 2,1
```